# Android Chrome ignoring -webkit-text-size-adjust:none property. Text is being scaled when zoomed out

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

Our client requested a website, but didn't want to pay for a mobile version. We still are making it work on mobile. When zoomed all the way out, Chrome on Android (4.0) is scaling a bunch of the text. We have tried setting the -webkit-text-size-adjust:none property, but it seems to be ignored and text is still being scaled up.

Works fine on iOS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the `-webkit-text-size-adjust` property you mention is non-standard. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-size-adjust).

Currently Chrome for Android scales text using [font boosting](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=FontBoosting) and there's no way to disable it.

If you want a way to disable font boosting, please provide your use-case and log an issue via [new.mcrbug.com](http://new.mcrbug.com).

Comment: Font boosting can be disabled by providing a `max-height` greater than the current height.  The linked webkit ticket suggests `max-height: 1000000px`.

Answer (score 32):

Just discovered a workaround for this. Set a max-height on a parent element of the text to be much larger than it would ever appear. For example,

```
<p class="intro">
  This is some text that is appearing blown up 
  and ridiculous on Chrome Mobile.
</p>

p.intro {
  max-height: 5000em;
}
```

You can set the max-height on any parent element. It doesn't have to be the first parent. For example,

```
<footer class="primary">
  <p class="intro">
    This is some text that is appearing blown up 
    and ridiculous on Chrome Mobile.
  </p>
</footer>

footer.primary {
  max-height: 5000em;
}
```

Comment: This, as well as the answer that was accepted should both be the answers

Comment: but why..? Can you explain?

Comment: This is incredible. Can't upvote more. The accepted answer doesn't work for me, hope it does for others

Comment: I can confirm this is working for me, too. Awesome! I've targeted the CSS at Android browsers only just in case this causes any unwanted effects on other devices.

Comment: yep, working also for me. Annoying problem and solved in an instant. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank god that there's a solution for it!

Comment: I think some of [supperss adjustment contitions](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-size-adjust/) are triggered for this hack.

Answer (score 6):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">` in the `<head>` tag could disable zoom

Comment: This worked great to disable the screwy chrome resizing on mobile. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with Firefox on Android.

The solution for me was to **add the style "float: left;" to the div containing the problem text.**

You might need to set the width of the div to the same as the parent (in pixels or 100%) to ensure it doesn't affect the rest of the divs.

See [How to prevent mobile browser from resizing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802777/how-to-prevent-mobile-browser-from-resizing-text)

Answer (score 3):

`-webkit-text-size-adjust:none` is so horrible!

I have poor eye site and constantly have my pages at 200% default zoom.  With `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none`, I cannot read anything, and my **only** alternative is to use Firefox.  It's my number one problem these days when browsing.

Too many sites use this, especially embedded Facebook comments on web pages. You should stop using it and create an interface that will work with any-sized font.

Comment: Except it doesn't zoom everything, just what it considers "important", totally breaking CSS.