# Different rendering of font-size on Android and desktop browsers

Tags: css, firefox, font-size, android-browser

I'm wondering why the font-size can be so different on my desktop and on my Android (the default browser, Chrome, on an up-to-date system).

In summary, the font-size in `<p>` (paragraphs) is too big on Android.

I use a [CSS reset stylesheet (article in french)](http://www.alsacreations.com/astuce/lire/654-feuille-de-styles-de-base.html).

### Firefox 25.0 on Linux

[image: Firefox 25.0]

You can see that the text of the *Lorem ipsum* paragraph is decreased (relatively to the text of the page). The *Title* has larger text.

### Android Chrome (cropped)

[image: Chrome on Android]

The size of the text in the *Lorem ipsum* paragraph is close to the size of the *Title*. Why Chrome don't display the text with a smaller size?

### Example

See the jsfiddle: [edit](http://jsfiddle.net/VLBP7/), [fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/VLBP7/embedded/result/) and [fullscreen without jsfiddle bar](http://fiddle.jshell.net/VLBP7/show/light/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be running into this [known issue](https://support.google.com/chrome/known-issues/2451255?hl=en) in Chrome for Android. Relevant text below:

> Font size is inconsistent on some sites, such as Reddit and T-Mobile.
>
> We're working on improving the display of non-mobile sites on phones, especially ones that use a large range of styles and fonts.

Comment: Since I observed the same problem on various websites, I think that it's related to the browser itself and not my code. Thanks

Comment: Just to add some context, Android doesn't like fonts smaller than 8px and will actively increase any value to that as a minimum.

Answer (score 7):

The topic is old but still..

I found some workarounds for this. Still fighting though:

1. If you force the paragraph to have a height, it turns normal again.
2. Setting `<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>` also fixes all paragraphs instantly.

Enjoy.

Comment: This is still the best solution I have found at the end of 2019. The meta tag fixes this issue in Marshmallow (Android 6).

Answer (score 3):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">` in the `<head>` tag could disable zoom on Android devices

Answer (score 2):

Could use `-webkit-text-size-adjust` / `text-size-adjust` property

edit: check this [Android Chrome ignoring -webkit-text-size-adjust:none property. Text is being scaled when zoomed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694767/android-chrome-ignoring-webkit-text-size-adjustnone-property-text-is-being-sc)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in Chrome on my iPhone. Have you tried another browser on your Android device to see if you get a different result?

[image]

Also, I would remove that huge CSS reset and start with more basic CSS. That makes things like this easier to debug. How about starting with: http://jsfiddle.net/mb8Db/1/

```
<style>
body {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
/* failing on Android */
 body > main > article {
    font-size:1em;
}
body > main > article p {
    font-size:0.75em;
}
</style>

<main>
     <h3>Header</h3>
    <article>
        <header>
             <h3>Title</h3>
        </header>
        <p>Paragraph</p>       
    </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no problem in your jsfiddle on my Android phone, the size is correct. The CSS stylesheet in my question only contains relevant rules.