# Disable Chrome (Accessibility->Resizing text)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

i have two question
this is my JS. document

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready( function(){
        $(window).height();
        $(window).width();
})

$(document).ready( function(){
   
   $(".logo").css("height", ((($(window).height()*37.38)/100)));
   $(".logo").css("width", "auto");
   
       
    
   $(".immaginefesta").css("height", ((($(window).height()*25)/100)));
   $(".immaginefesta").css("width", ((($(window).height()*25)/100)));
   $(".immaginefesta").css("border-radius", ((($(window).height()*40)/100)));
   
   
   $(".testievento").css("font-size", ((($(window).height()*2)/100)));
   
    $(".testinavbar").css("font-size", ((($(window).height()*3)/100)));
    $(".testinavbar").css("margin-left", ((($(window).height()*5)/100)));
 


          $(".titlebar").css("font-size", ((($(window).height()*3)/100)));
  
   
   
 
    
   
})

$(window).resize( function(){
 
 
     $(".logo").css("height", ((($(window).height()*37.38)/100)));
   $(".logo").css("width", "auto");
   
       
    
   $(".immaginefesta").css("height", ((($(window).height()*25)/100)));
   $(".immaginefesta").css("width", ((($(window).height()*25)/100)));
   $(".immaginefesta").css("border-radius", ((($(window).height()*40)/100)));
   
   
   $(".testievento").css("font-size", ((($(window).height()*2)/100)));
   
    $(".testinavbar").css("font-size", ((($(window).height()*3)/100)));
    $(".testinavbar").css("margin-left", ((($(window).height()*5)/100)));
 


          $(".titlebar").css("font-size", ((($(window).height()*3)/100)));
   
   
})
```

with internet explorer, firefox, safari anche chrome for pc there aren't any problems, but with google chrome i've a problem, if i go to (Accessibility, and put the resizing text to 60%) it looks perfect, how can i solve this problem auto?

2-is there a way to change the icon when i save the page from Safari for iphone on the app, or from android?

Answer (score 0):

These guys found a solution for Chrome's accessibility resizing (set a very high max-height), it worked for me too:

[Android Chrome ignoring -webkit-text-size-adjust:none property. Text is being scaled when zoomed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694767/android-chrome-ignoring-webkit-text-size-adjustnone-property-text-is-being-sc)